# Visual Studio Windows Service Project and Service Name

Tags: visual-studio, windows-services

I have a windows service project and a setup project. I can't figure out how to change the name of the actual service when it is installed (the name listed in windows services . . . services.msc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you view the properties for the installer class there is a property called ServiceName which dictates what the name will be in the list of services.

Answer (score 0):

Change the "DisplayName" in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<Service Name>` subkey.

Comment: The issue is is that I need to reinstall this service a lot and I want to be able to set the name of the service on install.

Comment: Oops. Missed the "setup project".